# Solspace Calendar Dates Not Showing Correctly

Tags: solspace-calendar

Running EE 2.7.3 and Solspace Calendar 1.8.5

The mini-calendar [here](http://opteracreative.com/~mac/) (bottom right) displays all dates that have events using this code:

```
<div id="mc_wrap">
   {exp:calendar:cal
      {if segment_2 == "calendars"}
         date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"
      {/if}
      {if segment_2 == "edit"}
         date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"
      {/if}
      {if segment_2 == "create"}
         date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"
      {/if}
      {if segment_2 == "event"}
         date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"
      {/if}
      {if segment_2 == ""}
         date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"
      {/if}
      {if segment_2 == "month"}
         {if segment_3 == ''}date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"{/if}
         {if segment_3 != ''}date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-01" date_range_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-last"{/if}
      {/if}
      {if segment_2 == "week"}
         {if segment_3 == ''}date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"{/if}
         {if segment_3 != ''}date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-01" date_range_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-last"{/if}
      {/if}
      {if segment_2 == "day"}
         {if segment_3 == ''}date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"{/if}
         {if segment_3 != ''}date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-01" date_range_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-last"{/if}
      {/if}
   dynamic="off"
   }
      <div id="mc_calendar">
         {display_each_month}
         <table id="mini-cal">
            <thead>
                    <tr  id="mc_head">
                  <th colspan="1">{if segment_2 != "calendars"}<a id="mc_prev_month" class="icon left" href="{path=''}mini-cal/month/{prev_month format="%Y/%m"}/">&laquo;</a>{/if}</th>

                  <th colspan="5"><a href="{path='calendar'}/{month format="%Y/%m"}/">{month format="%F %Y"}</a></th>

                  <th colspan="1">{if segment_2 != "calendars"}<a id="mc_next_month" class="icon right" href="{path=''}mini-cal/month/{next_month format="%Y/%m"}/"> &raquo;</a>{/if}</th>
           </tr>
           <tr id="mc_days">
              {display_each_day_of_week}
              <th class="{if day_of_week_is_weekend}weekend{/if} {if day_of_week_is_current}current{/if}">{day_of_week_one}</th>
              {/display_each_day_of_week}
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           {display_each_week}
           <tr>
              {display_each_day}
              <td class="
                 {if !day_in_current_month == FALSE}mc_pad{/if}
                 {if day_event_total > 0}has_events{/if}
                 {if count == 7}selected{/if}
                 {if day_is_today}today{/if}
              "><div class="mc_date">{if day_in_current_month}
                 {if day_event_total}<a href="{path='calendar/day'}/{day format="%Y/%m/%d"}/">{/if}
                 {day}
                 {if day_event_total}</a>{/if}
                 {if:else}
                    <strong class="middot">&middot;</strong>
                 {/if}</div></td>
              {/display_each_day}
           </tr>
           {/display_each_week}
        </tbody>
     </table>
     {/display_each_month}
  </div>
{/exp:calendar:cal}
</div>
```

Clicking on the day takes you to [this page](http://opteracreative.com/~mac/calendar/day/2014/06/15/). This works but with problems: the page displays a list of the days events and in most cases lists the day and date at the top using this code:

```
 <div id="main-content">
    {exp:calendar:cal
                date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-{segment_5}"
                show_days="1"
                limit="1"
            }

    <h2>Events for {event_start_date format="%D, %M %d, %Y"}</h2>
    {/exp:calendar:cal}

    {exp:calendar:events
                date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-{segment_5}"
                date_rande_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-{segment_5}"
                orderby="event_start_date"
                sort="asc"
                show_days="1"
            }

            <div class="inner"> 
                {if calendar_no_results}
                    No Results
                {/if}
            <div class="event-summary">
                <div class="details">
                    <span class="event-title"><a href="{path='calendar/event'}/{event_url_title}/{segment_3}/{segment_4}/{segment_5}">{event_title}</a></span>
                        {event_summary}
                        <p><b>Location</b>: {event_location}</p>
                        <p class="learn-more" ><a href="{path='calendar/event'}/{event_url_title}/{segment_3}/{segment_4}/{segment_5}">Learn more&raquo;</a></p> 
                </div>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end .inner -->
        {/exp:calendar:events}
    </div><!-- end #main-content -->
```

For some reason the day/date information is not displaying correctly, even though it is reading from the URL.

For example if I click on May 24, the linked page displays Friday May 23, 2014. If I click on Monday, May 26, the linked page displays Thurs May 29, 2014. Clearly we have a problem.

And then, if I click on June 18, the linked page does not display any Day/Date at all.

I am open to all possible solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Useful/Important Read**: http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/getting_started/

Next, you have

```
date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-{segment_5}"
```

..whereas your URL is

```
/~mac/calendar/day/2014/05/29/
```

Shouldn't that be the following?:

```
date_range_start="{segment_4}-{segment_5}-{segment_6}"
```

Further, in both cases, you need to use **`{exp:calendar:cal}`, which is the only tag that deals with event data on a chronological timeline**. {exp:calendar:events orderby="event_start_date"} won't be accurate, `{exp:calendar:cal}` is what would be used instead.

Finally, looks like you want to **zoom in on a particular date**, in that case you need to use:

```
{exp:calendar:cal
    date_range_start="{segment_4}-{segment_5}-{segment_6}"
    date_range_end="{segment_4}-{segment_5}-{segment_6}"
    pad_short_weeks="n"}
```

This will **zoom in** on a specific day, and limit the timeframe to that single day.

You need to have `pad_short_weeks=""` parameter set to `n` in the event you're trying to display anything other than a typical calendar display. When set to `n`, weeks won't be "padded" to the nearest first day of the week and last day of the week, as Calendar does this by default for the sake of properly outputting and formatting a calendar.

So for example, using the `date_range_start=""` and `date_range_end=""` parameters, if your code looks like this:

```
date_range_start="2011-10-19" date_range_end="2011-10-21"
```

...with `pad_short_weeks=""` parameter NOT specified, Calendar will automatically display the entire week range (2011-10-16 - 2011-10-22). With `pad_short_weeks="n"`, Calendar will just display the selected range (2011-10-19 - 2011-10-21).

[image]
<sub>(source: [solspace.com](http://www.solspace.com/documentation/calendar/images/calendar_pad_short_weeks.gif))</sub>

Finally, you have a separate `{exp:calendar:cal}` tag to display "Events for `{event_start_date format="%D, %M %d, %Y"}`" text. Although there are more than one way to display this data (since you have the date in the URL, you could combine that with {exp:calendar:**date**}, for example), the code as you have it will obviously loop through events, so will display the text more than once. Adding a `{if count == 1} ... {/if}` conditional should fix that and display the text once.

Comment: Hi Solspace, thank you for the detailed response. A couple of points: this site is in dev at the moment and the /~mac/ is the root of the site so {segment_3} is correct. When I change exp:calendar:events to exp:calendar:cal, I get events displaying 6 times on the same day. Your thoughts?

Comment: Any possibility we could get some more input on this? The above solution is worse than the current problem. Thanks.

Comment: For this entry that is repeating 6 times, how did you set up your event entry? Please provide the start/end date/time repeat pattern that you set up in the entry form. Also, please update the OP with your latest code. Thanks

Comment: I just updated the code and added a new date. I would be happy to provide access to the CP so you can view the templates if that would help. There are several entries that are repeating events with no end date. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not sure I see where your update was made in the OP. I also don't see any new information about how you set up your event in the entry form, which is likely the last thing to look into with this current solution. Since this is getting confusing and need a closer look, please open a ticket at support.solspace.com, and provide your URL and template group/name, the template code, CP credentials (URL, username, and password), and the entry_id and title of the event entry you're having problems with. Thanks. **Update**: Also please refer to this thread.

Comment: This was resolved as described in the answer after all (i.e. use `{exp:calendar:cal}` and `pad_short_weeks="n"`). Only a small comment to the first {exp:calendar:cal} tag code (to display the "Event for ..." text) was added to the solution at the end.

Comment: Excellent. This made all the difference. Thank you.